# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Desktop: failed - Nginx server installation and configuration

Tags: 18.04, nginx, reverse-proxy

i am new to Linux, using below guide lines to use reverse proxy (as other guide required it), but when issuing command for certbot as below, it is showing error, the contents of what it resulted on screen is here, please guide and help to resolve the problem.

guide link:
https://linuxize.com/post/secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04/

command issued:

```
sudo certbot certonly --agree-tos --email admin@example.com --webroot -w /var/lib/letsencrypt/ -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

screen output:

```
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator webroot, Installer None
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for example.com
http-01 challenge for www.example.com
Using the webroot path /var/lib/letsencrypt for all unmatched domains.
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Failed authorization procedure. www.example.com (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://www.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/ameVqhIT7MDOLg14nyeds58FskkEdJgQVML0tvy9d5E [2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946]: "<!doctype html>\n<html>\n<head>\n    <title>Example Domain</title>\n\n    <meta charset=\"utf-8\" />\n    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-type", example.com (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/HP2HDgSV7StnrURJnzMfnb0_pMabrWbd3wfquqpfHsA [2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946]: "<!doctype html>\n<html>\n<head>\n    <title>Example Domain</title>\n\n    <meta charset=\"utf-8\" />\n    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-type"

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: www.example.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://www.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/ameVqhIT7MDOLg14nyeds58FskkEdJgQVML0tvy9d5E
   [2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946]: "<!doctype
   html>\n<html>\n<head>\n    <title>Example Domain</title>\n\n
   <meta charset=\"utf-8\" />\n    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-type"

   Domain: example.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/HP2HDgSV7StnrURJnzMfnb0_pMabrWbd3wfquqpfHsA
   [2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946]: "<!doctype
   html>\n<html>\n<head>\n    <title>Example Domain</title>\n\n
   <meta charset=\"utf-8\" />\n    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-type"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

Comment: I guess I miss the point of posting that pic with the giant cookies notice cover a large bit of the screen.

Comment: And of course your DNS configuration is correct, your nginx server is running, and the directory `${webroot}/.well-known/acme-challenge` is accessible to the challenge script?

Comment: If your server is not running or configured you can use DNS challenge instead, which requires you to enter a TXT record directly in your DNS configuration to validate.

Comment: thanks @ArturMeinild , i don't know how to ... please guide me for this (DNS challange) or point me to the web page from where i can get help. regards

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have a step-by-step guide ready. The [certbot documentation](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#getting-certificates-and-choosing-plugins) may guide you for now.

Comment: no problem, i am searching on net, hope i will find some useful guidance. regards